# WMBT msg flow class inherit error

Tags: messagebroker

I'm trying to build websphere message broker however I've stumbled into weird issue. When using mqsicreatebar to create BAR file the build returns following error trice (three times, with different problem number):

```
Problem 22: Resource - /ErrorHandlingLib/error/handling/ErrorHandler.subflow; Error message - Class should inherit from MbJavaComputeNode..
```

I have found solution for this in one of the forums which stated that adding full class path to MbJavaComputeNode (as in: extends com.ibm.broker.javacompute.MbJavaComputeNode) the problem should be solved. However it was older wmbt version and neither this, neither any of the new IBM released wmbt fixes helped.

The error printing three times is probably because Java compute node in the sublfow is used in three different routes.

Websphere message broker toolkit used is v8.0.0.5

Answer (score 1):

The classes, that you assign to the Java Compute nodes in your flows must extend the MbJavaComputeNode class. 
This error says that you have some Java Computes that are not referencing such classes.

I suggest creating the classes for the Java Compute nodes with the wizard, which starts when you double click a newly inserted Java Compute node which has no class assigned to it.

Comment: its was merely a project file reference bugs =]